# Python-Error: '>' and '<' not supported by 'int' or 'str'

Tags: python

I am experiencing an error in my code of which I cannot use < or > in input mechanics. My goal is a guess the number game with 5 attempts at guessing the number, but this error won't allow me to implement the mechanic of hinting to the player to guess higher or lower! Any help is requested!

My code:

```
n = 1
rolltime = 0
import random
def rolldice(n):
        dice = []
        for i in range(n):
            dice.append(random.randint(1,50))
        return dice
roll = rolldice(n)
print("Try to guess my number! You have 5 tries! It is between 1 and 50.")
rolldice(n)
while rolltime < 6:
    rollguess = int(input("What do you think it is? "))
    if rollguess == roll:
        print("You guessed it! Good job!")
        rolltime = rolltime + 6
    else:
        if rollguess < roll:
            print("Your guess was too low! Try again. ")
        elif rollguess > roll:
            print("Your guess was too high! Try again.")
        rolltime = rolltime + 1
```

The error I recieve:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-78e886a91aa0> in <module>
     16         rolltime = rolltime + 6
     17     else:
---> 18         if rollguess < roll:
     19             print("Your guess was too low! Try again. ")
     20         elif rollguess > roll:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: `rolldice` returns a list. `roll = rolldice(n)` assigns a list to `roll`. `rollguess < roll` tries to compare an integer to a list which will not work as stated by the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ian commented, you are trying to compare a number to a list of numbers. If you want to compare the number they guessed with the first number in the list, you could try something like `dice[0]` to get the 0-th (first) element in the list:

```py
n = 1
rolltime = 0
import random
def rolldice(n):
        dice = []
        for i in range(n):
            dice.append(random.randint(1,50))
        return dice
roll = rolldice(n)
print("Try to guess my number! You have 5 tries! It is between 1 and 50.")
rolldice(n)
while rolltime < 6:
    rollguess = int(input("What do you think it is? "))
    if rollguess == roll[0]:
        print("You guessed it! Good job!")
        rolltime = rolltime + 6
    else:
        if rollguess < roll[0]:
            print("Your guess was too low! Try again. ")
        elif rollguess > roll[0]:
            print("Your guess was too high! Try again.")
        rolltime = rolltime + 1
```

However, if intended for the variable `dice` to contain possible answers to the game, you will have to store an answer in a separate variable, like this:

```py
# ...
n = 1
dice = rolldice(n)
answer = random.choice(dice) # Obviously, this is the same as accessing dice[0] for  n=1

# ...

if (rollguess == answer):
    # ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare list and numbers.

```
rolltime = 0
import random
def rolldice():
        return random.randint(1,50)
roll = rolldice()
print("Try to guess my number! You have 5 tries! It is between 1 and 50.")
while rolltime < 6:
    rollguess = int(input("What do you think it is? "))
    if rollguess == roll:
        print("You guessed it! Good job!")
        rolltime = rolltime + 6
    else:
        if rollguess < roll:
            print("Your guess was too low! Try again. ")
        elif rollguess > roll:
            print("Your guess was too high! Try again.")
        rolltime = rolltime + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to simplify the function to avoid your problem with list. Also added parameters for flexibility when needed.

```
import random

def roll_dice(min_num=1, max_num=50, max_guess=6):
    roll = random.randint(min_num,max_num)

    #print(roll)  for testing purposes only
    print(f'Try to guess the number! You have {max_guess} tries!\
    It is between {min_num} to {max_num}.')

    while max_guess != 0:
        rollguess = int(input('What do you think it is? '))
        if rollguess == roll:
            print("You guess it right! Good job!")
            break
        elif rollguess < roll:
            print("You're guess is too low! Try again. ")
            max_guess -= 1
        else:
            print("You're guess is too high! Try again. ")
            max_guess -= 1

roll_dice()
```